# Where does '.' and '..' come from?

Tags: unix, shell, history

What's the story behind our massive repitition of `./foo` and `cd ..`. Where do these two `.` and `..` come from? Where could they be seen as a way of navigating a file system tree for the first time?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Excerpt from an [interview with Ken Thompson](http://www.princeton.edu/~hos/mike/transcripts/thompson.htm) (9-6-89):

> Every time we made a directory, by
>   convention we put it in another
>   directory called directory -
>   directory, which was dd. Its name was
>   dd and that all the users directories
>   and in fact most other directories,
>   users maintain their own directory
>   systems, had pointers back to dd, **and
>   dd got shortened into ‘dot-dot,’** and
>   dd was for directory-directory.

Comment: Additional related trivia, https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry I can't answer properly, but I can recommend these links:

- [The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/hist.html) and
- [A Brief history of the BSD Fast File System](http://www.usenix.org/publications/login/2007-06/openpdfs/mckusick.pdf)

for some interesting historical notes on early file systems and their use.

Other than that, the earliest reference I've found is the 1974 paper "[The UNIX Time-Sharing System](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/unix.pdf)" by Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson. The precursor of UNIX, Multics, also had hierarchical file systems and the notion of relative paths, but according to "[Introduction to MULTICS](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-123.pdf)" it used another notation for that.

Comment: Multics used `<` to go up and `>` to go down the tree. E.g. `cwd <<<<higher>lower>file` goes up 4 levels then goes down to `lower`, `file`. That has always seemed more practical to me than `../` but...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was invented by Dennis Ritchie at Bell Labs in the early years of Unix.