# Reasons for the implementation of "." as representation of current working directory

Tags: python, filesystems, relative-path

I'm wondering if there exists a reason why `.` was implemented to represent current working directory. For example in Python, `os.mkdir("test")` and `os.mkdir("./test")` will produce the same result, which then makes `.` redundant.

Is there a specific case where the use of `.` is necessary to achieve a desired result?

Comment: Actually, `os.mkdir(".\test")` will give you a directory with a tab character in its name, but that's beside the point. =)

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right, I fixed it.

Comment: Not really a Python question, since it's handled by the operating system. This might be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496989

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280656/where-does-and-come-from